# Python Selenium binding with Tor browser 7.x

Tags: python, selenium, tor

I need your help to make automation with Tor Browser + Python Selenium on Windows.

I am using selenium 3.4.3 with Tor Browser 7.0.1, and the code initializing the TOR web driver is as following

```
    binary = FirefoxBinary(TOR_BINARY_PATH)
    prof = FirefoxProfile(TOR_PROFILE_PATH)

    prof.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
    prof.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_host', '127.0.0.1')
    prof.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9150)
    prof.update_preferences()

    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=prof, firefox_binary=binary)
```

However, i am stuck with the error 'Tor failed to start' each time i run the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your Tor Browser, or establish a Tor connection before running the script. You can do that by either run Tor in terminal, or simply start Tor browser